# Localization principle in supersymmetry

Tags: reference-request, mirror-symmetry, supersymmetry, supermanifolds

In $\S$ 9.3 of the book "Mirror symmetry" (Vafa, Zaslow eds.) the authors formulate the following general localization principle for computation of integrals with respect to both even and odd variables: Assume there is some supersymmetry transformation of variables. **Then the integral becomes localized on the field configurations for which the fermionic variables are invariant under the supersymmetry.**

I would like to understand the precise meaning of this sentence. Though several non-trivial and beautiful applications are discussed in the book, I do not understand how they are deduced from this principle due to the fact that the principle itself seems to be too vague. The explanation on pp.158-159 how it works is too concise for me, and it is not clear how that example can be generalized to other situations.

**Question: how to formulate a precise statement behind this principle (the situation of finite dimensional integrals would be enough for me for the moment)? Can I read a proof of it somewhere?**

Comment: I know nothing about Mirror symmetry and the book you mentioned. But what you are asking looks like the Atiyah Bott localization formula. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_formula_for_equivariant_cohomology

Comment: I think it is a different localization formula.

Comment: There is a thorough answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/28079/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Theorem 1 in "Supersymmetry and Localization" by Schwarz and Zaboronsky.

Comment: Here is a link to the preprint: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9511112